# Unable to publish .hyper file to Tableau site

Tags: python, tableau-api

I'm trying to publish a `.hyper` file using python and in terms of the library, I'm using `tableauserverclient` and `tableauhyperapi`. Everything is working file starting from creating the `.hyper` file, signing in the tableau server, fetching all the projects available on the site and server. The only thing that is throwing an error is when it comes to publishing.

Points to be noted:

1. I'm following this Github [repo](https://github.com/tableau/hyper-api-samples/tree/main/Community-Supported/publish-hyper).
2. I'm using `TableauAuth` class to login into the server via user credentials.
3. I have checked my user has **Site Administrator Explorer** access.

Any kind of advice or help would be much appreciated.

[image: Error]

Comment: One limitation of TSC when publishing a hyper is that the hyper can only have one table. Does your hyper have only a single table?

Comment: Yes it has only one table

Comment: Request your admin to grant you a PAT token with full access and then use it to publish